# why square matrix is group for multipy

Tags: matrices, group-theory, linear-groups

There are 4 requirements in order to be group
for $$(R^{n*n},*), n\in{N}$$

1. Closer $ \forall{A,B}\in{R^{n*n}}:A*B\in{R^{n*n}}$
2. Associativity $\forall{A,B,C}\in{R^{n*n}}:A*(B*C)=(A*B)*C$
3. Neutral element $\exists{I}\in{R^{n*n}},\forall{A}\in{R^{n*n}}:I*A=A*I=A$
4. Inverse element $\exists{X}\in{R^{n*n}},\forall{A}\in{R^{n*n}}:X*A=A*X=I$

so the question is, i dont understand why square matrix satisfy the inverse element requirements.

in my mathematic material, it say square matrix is group but **not every square matrixs are invertible, and in inverse element requirement, it use $\forall$ notation**.

for my understanding, the requirement should change like this($\forall$->$\exists$)
$$\exists{X,A}\in{R^{n*n}}:X*A=A*X=I$$

when we say $(R^{n*n},*), n\in{N}$, does it imply that it includes only matrix which is invertible?
or maybe i am missing some simple thing hopefully.

Comment: You are correct that not all square matrices are invertible.  Only the invertible ones are in the group

Comment: I removed the [tag:abelian-group] tag, because matrix multiplication is not generally commutative

Comment: Switch the quantifiers in axiom 4. As is, it reads that you find an X and that works for all A. But with the other way around you go over all A and for each of them you can find an X, but this time that choice is allowed to depend on A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that not all square matrices are invertible.  Only the invertible ones are in the group.  By the way, the group is called the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group).

Also, as pointed out in a comment by [AHusain](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/277089/ahusain), the fourth requirement should be written
$\forall{A}\in{R^{n*n}, \exists{X}\in{R^{n*n}}}:X*A=A*X=I$, so $X$ can depend on $A$.